# WillSet/DidSet not being invoked on realm property

Tags: swift, dynamic, realm, getter-setter

I have a problem because `willSet` and `didSet` are not being called with dynamic realm object.

Code sample:

```
try! realm.write {
    sut = Backup()
    realm.add(sut) // here willSet and didSet are invoked with nil object
}

XCTAssertFalse(sut.didEditPatient) // ok
try! realm.write {
    print("CHECKING: will add the patient")
    let patient = Patient()
    realm.add(patient)
    sut.patient = patient // nothing gets printed here!
    print("CHECKING: added the patient")
}

XCTAssertTrue(sut.didEditPatient) // fails
XCTAssertNotNil(sut.patient) // ok
```

Where Backup class is defined this way:

```
final class Backup: Object {
    @objc dynamic var patient: Patient? {
        willSet {
            print("CHECKING: willSet: \(String(describing: newValue))")
            if newValue != patient {
                didEditPatient = true
            }
        }
        didSet { print("CHECKING: didSet: \(String(describing: patient))") }
    }
    @objc dynamic var didEditPatient: Bool = false
```

Output in the console is:

- CHECKING: willSet: nil
- CHECKING: didSet: nil
- CHECKING: will add the patient
- CHECKING: added the patient

While I'd rather expect that between `will add the patient` and `added the patient` I should get `willSet` and `didSet` with patient object. Obviously, patient is not nil.

Comment: I posted an answer but now that I look at the code, something's wrong or I am overlooking something. Within your `realm.write` you're adding a new, empty patient `realm.add(Patient())` but then you're assigning a patient to sut like this `sut.patient = patient` but the question is where did that `patient` var come from? In other words, `patient` appears to be undefined `sut.patient = patient <---- This?`

Comment: @Jay You're right. That's a dummy code I wrote in SOF to simplify the real solution, and obviously I made a mistake here. Fixed that declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one issue described about this in realm repo:

---

I would recommend using a private persisted property which has no logic, along with a non-persisted computed property which has the willSet/didSet functionality:

```
class Model : RLMObject {
    private dynamic var backingProp = 0

    var prop : Int {
        get {
            return backingProp
        }
        set(newValue) {
            // do willSet stuff
            backingProp = newValue
            // do didSet stuff
        }
    }

    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject]! {
        return ["prop"]
    }
}
```

This is a bit verbose, but gives you identical behavior for objects in a realm and standalone objects.

---

Source: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/870#issuecomment-54543539

Comment: Welcome to SO! Link only answers are considered to be low-quality here. If the link becomes obsolete, your answer gives no information whatsoever. When quoting an off-site resource, please always make sure to include enough information in your answer so that it can be useful for future readers even if the link stops working. If that's not possible, you should leave a comment with the link instead of posting an answer.

Comment: Like this answer but I don't think it really answers the question; the OP wants to use willSet and didSet but have the prop property be managed by realm. You can actually do that without a backing property. More importantly though there's ambiguity in the question as it looks like they are attempting to set the property to an unmanaged property - see my comment to the question.

Comment: Cool. The only thing I'd point here, is that you don't have to `override ignoredProperties`. I'm inheriting from `Realm.Object` and only `@objc dynamic var` will be treated as Realm properties, everything else is ignored. Maybe with`RLMObject` it used to be different, but I guess that is not in available the modern Realm versions (I'm using realm/realm-cocoa 5.0). I even checked in Realm Browser to make sure, and such column will not be created.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to fix. Just update the objects properties before writing to Realm. willSet and didSet are Swift constructs, not Objc.

```
let p = Patient()
try! realm.write {
    print("CHECKING: will add the patient")
    sut.patient = p // moved before add to realm.
    realm.add(p)
    print("CHECKING: added the patient")
}
```

Will print

```
CHECKING: will add the patient
willSet
didSet
CHECKING: added the patient
```

Which is the order you want.

Comment: That is only right if we use it when the object has just been created and is not added to realm. If it has been added previously, then it still won't display the messages. What obviously can lead to bugs in production, eg someone edits the object, has a protocol method to update it eg. `func didUpdate(patient: Patient?)` where he also sets `backup.patient = oldValue`, because he can't know if the object was added, removed or edited and willSet/didSet will not trigger in all cases. So I prefer to stay with the other solution suggested in Realm issues page quoted above.

Comment: Besides, I've just tested it out of curiosity, and it does not work. `let patient = Patient(id: 5); try! realm.write {print("CHECKING: will add the patient"); sut.patient = patient; realm.add(patient); print("CHECKING: added the patient")}` and `@objc dynamic var patient: Patient? { willSet { print("willSet: \(String(describing: newValue))") }; didSet { print("didSet: \(String(describing: patient))") } }` results with `willSet: nil; didSet: nil; CHECKING: will add the patient; CHECKING: added the patient`

Comment: @Vive Interesting. That section in my answer after Will Print is a copy and paste from the Xcode Console which indicates, at least for the posted code, it does work in respect the functions being called. In your question those were not being called at all. It's curious why the newValue is nil though. I agree that having Swift properties backed by objc Realm objects is the best solution - especially with calculated values.

Comment: Indeed interesting. Did you test it with Realm or just empty playground? I'd like to point, that my comment above was also copied from my code, I changed that order yesterday. The nils were printed when creating the SUT before the 1st line. However in the place where I swap patient `sut.patient = p` nothing gets printed even if that's before adding to realm. In my question prints worked the same way. Anyway, I'm not going to continue with this solution, since it won't be working with updating later - as I wrote in the first comment. Interesting, thanks for your answer